# Updating csv with values generated

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv file HDFC.csv when called in a Dataframe it appears like

```
ef={'Date':['20.3.2019','21.3.2019','22.3.2019','24.3.2019','25.5.2019','29.6.2019','30.6.2019'],
'Quantity Bought':[342.0,2330.0,'nan','nan',344,'nan','nan'],
'Buy Price':[21.0,45.0,'nan','nan',22,'nan','nan'],
'Sell Quantity':['nan','nan',110,221,'nan',455,566],
'Sell Price':['nan','nan',56,21,'nan',29,30]}
 ef=pd.DataFrame(ef)
```

When i Run the below code

```
class Trade():
def __init__(self,date: pd.datetime, quantity: np.float32, price: np.float32):
    self.date = date
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.price = price
def printT(self):
    return print('Quantity: %i, Price: %f'%(self.quantity, self.price))

class Isin():
def __init__(self, isin, notinalPerQuantity, listOfTrades):
    self._isin = isin
    self._notinalPerQuantity = notinalPerQuantity
    self._listOfTrades = listOfTrades
def mtm(self, trade):
    return trade.quantity*trade.price*self._notinalPerQuantity
def __next__(self):
    return self._listOfTrades.__next__()
def __iter__(self):
    return self._listOfTrades.__iter__()

class transactionAccounting():
def __init__(self, isin):
    """
    Initiliase with first entry from left
    """
    print('Initialize trade que')
    self._Isin = isin
    self._notinalPerQuantity = isin._notinalPerQuantity
    self._trades = isin._listOfTrades
    t0 = self._trades[0]
    self._avgprice = 0
    self._quantity = 0
    self._pnl = 0
    self._bookvalue = 0
def printStat(self):
   quantity=self._quantity
   avg_price=self._avgprice
   pnl=self._pnl
   amount=self._bookvalue

def buy(self, trade):
    raise NotImplementedError

def sell(self, trade):
    raise NotImplementedError


class FifoAccount(transactionAccounting):
def __init__(self, trades):
    transactionAccounting.__init__(self, trades)
    self._deque = deque()
    for trade in self._trades:
        if trade.quantity>=0:
            self.buy(trade)
        else:
            self.sell(trade)
def buy(self, trade):
    print('Buy trade')
    trade.printT()
    self._deque.append(trade)
    self._bookvalue += self._Isin.mtm(trade) 
    self._quantity += trade.quantity
    self._avgprice = self._bookvalue / self._quantity / self._notinalPerQuantity
    avg_price=self._avgprice
    #buy_quant=self._quantity
    #bal=self._bookvalue
    #print(buy_quant)  
    #print(bal)




    self.printStat()
def sell(self, trade):
    print('Sell trade') 
    trade.printT()
    sellQuant = -trade.quantity
    while(sellQuant>0):
        lastTrade = self._deque.popleft()
        price = lastTrade.price
        quantity = lastTrade.quantity
        print('Cancel trade:')
        lastTrade.printT()
        if sellQuant >= quantity:
            self._pnl += -(price - trade.price)*quantity*self._notinalPerQuantity 
            self._quantity -= quantity
            self._bookvalue -= price * quantity * self._notinalPerQuantity
            sellQuant -= quantity
        else:
            self._pnl += -(price - trade.price)*sellQuant*self._notinalPerQuantity 
            self._quantity -= sellQuant
            self._bookvalue -= price * sellQuant * self._notinalPerQuantity
            lastTrade.quantity -= sellQuant
            self._deque.appendleft(lastTrade)
            sellQuant = 0 
        sell_quant=self._quantity
        bal_sell=self._bookvalue 
        pnl=self._pnl
        print(pnl)
        print(sell_quant)
        print(bal_sell)
        print(self._avgprice)
        self.printStat()
        assert(self._quantity > 0)

el = [Trade(pd.to_datetime('01.04.2016',format='%d.%m.%Y')+dt.timedelta(days=i), 5-i, 99.8+i) for i in range(0,100)]
#ef=pd.read_csv('D:\\PMS\\testport\\Portfolio Ledger\\Mutual Fund\\HDFC.csv')
#cols=[1,4,7,8,9,10,11]
#ef.drop(ef.columns[cols], axis=1,inplace=True)

ef.replace('nan', np.nan, inplace=True)

numberOfRows = len(ef.index)

el={'Date':[],
'Quantity':[],
'Price':[]}
el = list(el)

row = 0
i = 0

while i < numberOfRows:
if ef.isnull().iat[row,1] != True:
    Date=[ef.iat[row,0]]
    Quantity=ef.iat[row,1]
    Price=ef.iat[row,2]
    #el = el.append(adding, ignore_index=True)
    i += 1
    row += 1
    s=pd.Series([Date,Quantity,Price])
    el.append(Trade(pd.to_datetime(s[0],format='%d.%m.%Y'), s[1], s[2]))


else:
    Date=[ef.iat[row, 0]]
    Quantity=ef.iat[row, 3]*(-1)
    Price=ef.iat[row, 4]
    #el = el.append(adding, ignore_index=True)
    i += 1
    row += 1
    s=pd.Series([Date,Quantity,Price])
    el.append(Trade(pd.to_datetime(s[0],format='%d.%m.%Y'), s[1], s[2]))
del el[0]
del el[1]
del el[0]





b = Isin('bond', 1, el)
trans = FifoAccount(b)
```

When I run the above code it prints Balance Quantity,Avg.Price,PnL,Balance amount at every row ,I cant understand how to give these values to csv in which the above dataframe is present with the same column headers that is Balance Quantity,Avg.Price,PnL,Balance amount

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Its pretty tedious to look through that amount of code. Give an example of your goal DataFrame.

Comment: So basically the dataframe which i have is `df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Quantity Bought','Buy Price','Sell Quantity','Sell Price'])` and I want a df to be `df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Quantity Bought','Buy Price','Sell Quantity','Sell Price','Balace Quantity','Avg.Price','Profit & Loss','Balace cost'])` the last four columns are generated by taking the inputs from quantity bought,buy price,sell quantity,sell price

Comment: Iterate over the `el` list and save quantity and price in list and save them to the dataframe as `ef['price'] = list_of_price`

Comment: No  but quantities are coming from either the buy function or the sell function

Comment: Your problem is still not clear. You said you have trouble to save your values in the csv. You can write them in a new column in your DataFrame and save write it in a csv file again.

Comment: Yea basically it was adding these generated columns to the dataframe itself and updating the dataframe and the csv file,my problem is in the updating of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. load csv to pandas
2. generate new columns using `pandas.apply()`, so you can use your functions.
3. save the expanded dataframe to csv.